# python- how to print output in n lines

Tags: python, output, lines

```
 for r in range(0,11):
    print r
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

is there anyway to get output like

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

or as many lines as i want

but not with

```
for r in range (0,6):
    print r,
print
for r in range(6,11):
    print r,
```

this is just an example though
my program needs to print

```
* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* - * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* * - * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* - - - * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* * * - - * - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* - - - - - * - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* * - * - - - * - - - - - - - - - - - -
* - * - - - - - * - - - - - - - - - - -
* * - - * - - - - * - - - - - - - - - -
* - - - - - - - - - * - - - - - - - - -
* * * * - * - - - - - * - - - - - - - -
* - - - - - - - - - - - * - - - - - - -
* * - - - - * - - - - - - * - - - - - -
* - * - * - - - - - - - - - * - - - - -
* * - * - - - * - - - - - - - * - - - -
* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - * - - -
* * * - - * - - * - - - - - - - - * - -
* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - * -
* * - * * - - - - * - - - - - - - - - *
```

but i can only produce lines of every single character and one single line of all the characters.
so please help

Comment: hwang hyungchae you have edited the original question with a totally differnt question.  you should undo that edit and ask a new question instead.

Comment: sure. how do i undo an edit?

Comment: can i just delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` statement:

```
if r >= 0 and r < 6:
    print r
if r >= 6 and <= 10:
    print r,
```

Comment: is there anything i can put after print? because i'm using it to print something else that is not a range of numbers. and if i need it to be in more than two lines and with a wider range, it's going to be very tedious.

Comment: Can you give an example it's hard to understand what exactly you want to print.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> for i in izip_longest(*[iter(range(11))]*6, fillvalue=''):
...     print ' '.join(map(str, i))
... 
0 1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

There's probably a better solution

Comment: i realised i was stupid to not post my real question. if it is not too much to ask, can you provide me with the answer to my newly edited question? and than you for editing my other question a couple of days back.

Comment: @hwanghyungchae I reverted to your previous question, as it was a radical change. And no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

first make a list of the stuff you want print, and then use e.g. a simple modulo in the loop:

```
toprint=['*','-',1,2,'a','b','c','d',3,4,5,'-','l',0]

width=4

tmp=''
for i,char in enumerate(toprint):
   tmp=tmp+' '+str(char)
   if (i+1)%width==0:
      print tmp
      tmp=''
```

gives

```
 * - 1 2
 a b c d
 3 4 5 -
```

Comment: i realised i was stupid to not post my real question. if it is not too much to ask, can you provide me with the answer to my newly edited question?

Comment: It is not so stupid, it is common to many people to ask XY problems, see (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)